# How to generate custom amount orders in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, payment

I am looking for some solution, Where I can generate custom amount order from back end and directly sent payment invoice to my customer.

I want to sent custom invoice to my every customer, so from backend I can do this and send invoice link to my customer and they can pay.

Is there any way in magento2 to achieve this functionality?

Comment: are u want create a custom order and want to  invoice to every customer or a single customer

Comment: I want to send custom amount invoices to some customer. so in invoice they will have some link when they click on that link they will be redirected to site and it will land to cart page or checkout page so customer can pay for it.

Comment: I do not know if it is available in the Open Source version, but in the Enterprise Edition you can create an order and set custom price for each products from the customer admin page in the backend.

Comment: @FranckGarnier Thanks for your reply. Okay it is good that it is possible to do this in the enterprise edition. But my plan is to send an invoice of order after placing an order from backend and by that invoice, user can make payment.

Comment: It seems not possible natively. But I do not understand, if you create an invoice, for Magento the payment has been authorized or captured.

Comment: Yes It is not possible with native code, But I want a way that I can send invoice with pending status once they click on the invoice link they can come to magento website and then they can complete the payment  and order should be completed in backend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this. Follow below links

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-order-programmatically.html

https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-create-invoice-in-magento2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Till I know we must have product created in backend for which we are going to place an order. 
Above solution will only work if we have such amount's product. but in my case I wanted to send custom invoice with custom amounts every time. so customer click there and return to my website and make payment.